# Should I use the "for" attribute for <label> when I'm using it to label a text field or is it not necessary?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, label

When I use a checkbox or radio input, I usually use the for attribute, but is it really needed when I want to label a text input or any input other than a checkbox / radio?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: What is `LabelFor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. Not only does it programmatically connect the label to the text input (so screenreader users will be told what the text input is for), but it will also increase the 'click' area for the input, so clicking (or tapping) on the label will set the users focus to the corresponding field. 
If you don't want to use the 'for' attribute for whatever reason, you can wrap the text input in the label as well.

```html
<label> Text Input
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

This will have the same effect with increasing the click area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. It is very helpful for users of assistive technology: http://www.ucop.edu/electronic-accessibility/web-developers/advanced-tips/label-elements-in-forms-for-use-by-assistive-technology.html